# How can I clear the task of my App without calling startActivity() or finishAffinity()

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

I have four Activities open A,B,C,D ("A" activity is not my launcher activity) and the app is in background (i.e. Home button pressed).

Now based on some GCM message received I need to finish all the activities or clear the task. So that next time when user open the app a completely new activity "E" gets open.

So neither 1> I can not do startActivity with CLEAR_TASK flag

nor 2> finishAffinity() as I will not have activity reference.

3> There is a solution to use BroadcastReceiver and finish the Activities manually but in some low configuration mobiles this solution is giving problem.

So is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Why can't you do clear_task ?

Comment: Id suggest check onResume for the condition and open new activity accordingly. Also BroadcastReceiver solution sounds better- cant you fix the issues

Comment: @abhinav.. to do clear_task I need to do startActivity().. as application is in background ding so will bring app in the foreground always, which is bad user experience

Comment: @X3Btel.. I need to clear the task or finish all activities that was my requirement so onResume() solution not what I am looking for.. 
with BroadcastReceiver I explained a problem.. in some low configuration mobiles background process is getting restarted resulting in unregistering my receiver.

Comment: If it is in the background you should not care for the stack. Thats why there is onResume- to check if the content is still up to date and refresh UI accordingly

Comment: @X3Btel .. Because otherwise User can open Activity "A" (say) from recent task.. which I can not allow once GCM message received so if I need to finish "A"

Comment: What is it you exactly want ? When you open via notification E activity opens ! Right ! So can you please tell why you want A,B,C,D to be cleared ? Is it in case user presses back button ? What behaviour do you want if the user presses the back button ?

Comment: If you implement your code in onResume the user wont be able to open it. onResume ic completed before showing the UI to the user. I believe this is exactly the usecase you have

Comment: When did I say I want to open by tapping on notification? Please read my question again.. when I am receiving the GCM msg user should not be able to go to any of the A,B,C,D activities which he can open via recent apps, so I need to finish them.
Irrespective of the purpose the goal is to clear the task or finish those activities

Comment: @X3Btel .. u r right but for example I told you there are 4 activities but there are many more like 30 activities.. so I can not add the code in the onResume of all of them 

and due to some difficulties (of legacy code) neither I can create a single parent activity and add the code there.. so that my requirement is like the above

Comment: So if this is what you want, you can always kill the whole app when you are handling the notification !

Comment: If thats the case- Implement Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks in your Application class. And then do your checks in onActivityResumed . It should still do the checks before showing any UI

Answer (score 0):

When you are handling the notification you can kill the app by doing the following

**android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())**

The four components - Activity, Service, Content Provider, Broadcast Receiver runs in separate thread under one process. So when you will be requesting myPid() it will be giving the same id of the process which also has your activities !

I hope this solves your problem !